# Access not displaying Null values

Tags: database, ms-access, isnull

I have an SQL query for tables type, Supplier, person, makeModel, make, item, glCode and contact. When I run this query, it just shows values that have supplierID, but for other items there are no SupplierIDs. The field is blank for most of the items. Running this query does not give me items that have Null values. How do I modify this query to display that as well?

```
SELECT
    item.ID,
    type.type,
    make.make,
    makeModel.model,
    item.serialNumber,
    item.note,
    item.purchaseDate,
    item.purchaseCost,
    item.disposalDate,
    Supplier.supplier,
    person.person
FROM Supplier
INNER JOIN (person INNER JOIN ((make INNER JOIN (type INNER JOIN makeModel ON type.[ID] = makeModel.[typeID]) ON make.[ID] = makeModel.[makeID]) INNER JOIN item ON makeModel.[ID] = item.[makeModelID]) ON person.[ID] = item.[personID]) ON  item.[supplierID]=Supplier.[ID];
```

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: I can't follow your query because you wrote it in a very convoluted way.  But I can suggest that you use `LEFT JOIN` everywhere instead of inner join.  This might fix the problem right away; if not it should at least help.

Comment: It says JOIN expression not supported.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I got it working using RIGHT join. But thank you for the idea. Thanks.